# Javascript multidimensional array error

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array, counter

I try in angular controller fill 2D array with data, but i get error  Cannot set property '0' of undefined at controllers.js:74 .

Here is code:

```
    var firstmatchday = 1;
    var empty = [[],[]];    
    var counter1 = 0;
    var counter2 = 0;
    $scope.fixtures = data.fixtures;

    for(i=0; i<data.fixtures.length; i++)
    {   
        if(data.fixtures[i].matchday == firstmatchday)
        {
            empty[counter1][counter2++] = data.fixtures[i];
        }
        else
        {   
            counter1++;
            counter2 = 0;
            firstmatchday++;
            empty[counter1][counter2++] = data.fixtures[i]; // line 74
            //console.log(data.fixtures[i]);
        }
    }
```

What is wrong with my code?

Thanks, Tomislav

Comment: (1) We have no knowledge about what is  `data.fixtures` (2) In the `else` the variable `counter2` is always reset to 1 and you set `empty[counter1][0]`. Is this correct?

Comment: I fixed code and it now works, with adding empty[counter1] = []; after counter1++ , but i dont know how it work and why error occured...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first loop:

- firstmatchday === 1
- counter1 === 0
- counter2 === 0
- i === 0

Assuming `data.fixtures[0].matchday !== 1`

- firstmatchday === 2
- counter1 === 1
- counter2 === 0
- empty[1][0] === [] // OK to assign data.fixtures[0]
- counter2 === 1

On the next loop:
- i === 1

Assuming `data.fixtures[1].matchday !== 2`

- firstmatchday === 3
- counter1 === 2
- counter2 === 0
- empty[2][0] === undefined[0] // ERROR cannot assign data.fixtures[1]
- counter2 === 1

This would cause an error as JS would interpret `empty[2]` first and see that it is `undefined`. So `empty[2][0]` is equivalent to `undefined[0]` which would cause an error. That is why adding `empty[counter1] = []` solves the issue as `empty[2]` is equal to `[]` in the example now and therefore `empty[2][0]` is accessible.

Answer (score 1):

You cant use 2D arrays in javascript , it doesnt exists, if it must be 2nd dimension it must be object

```
empty = {
  property1 : {
    property : "foo"
  }
}
```

empty[property1][property] === "foo" will return true you cant do [[],[]] as in php because array in javascript is either simple [1,2,3] or [{},{},{}] actualy ther is not something like

```
empty = [
  0 : [
   property : value
  ] 
]
```

but there is

```
empty = [
 {
  property : value
 }
]
```

you can access it as empty[0].property
if you have array

```
empty = ["foo","bar"];
```

empty[1] will return "bar"

if you have object

```
empty = [
 {
   property : "bar"
  }
]

var _prop = "property";
empty[0][_prop] will return also "bar"
```

its because when you dont know actual property or index name (it is dynamicaly accessed you cant use dot notation

empty.0._prop because it will look for

```
empty = {
  0 : {
   _prop : "bar"
 } 
}
```

So it is only interpolation method for javascript to access dynamic properties/indexes inside object /arrays

```
var firstmatchday = 1;
    var empty = {};    
    var counter1 = 0;
    var counter2 = 0;
    $scope.fixtures = data.fixtures;

    for(i=0; i<data.fixtures.length; i++)
    {   
        if(data.fixtures[i].matchday == firstmatchday)
        {
            if(emtpy[counter1] === undefined)
            {
              empty[counter1] = {};
            }
            if(empty[counter1][counter2++] === undefined)
            {
              empty[counter1][counter2++] = {};
            }
            empty[counter1][counter2++] = data.fixtures[i];
        }
        else
        {   
            counter1++;
            counter2 = 0;
            firstmatchday++;
            empty[counter1][counter2++] = data.fixtures[i]; // line 74
            //console.log(data.fixtures[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In javascript, almost everything is an object (to be honest I don't know any exceptions). See: `new Array() instanceof Object` is true. And of course you can use 2d arrays. At the end its just an array with items as arrays. The `var foo = {}` notation is for object literals. You don't need this to define an array.

Comment: yes , thats exactly what i wanted say, there is nothing like 2D array, but you can represent it like nested object or [{ prop : [{},{}] , }] , i just wanted clarify differences with other languages, so you just must understand duck typing, if its look like 2D array, if its behaviour like 2D array, if you can access it as 2D array, it is 2D array, but in reality its nested object.

Comment: @MilosMosovsky I don't think I understand your point. Are you saying that `var arr = [[], []];` is invalid in JS?

Comment: var arr = [[1,2] , [1,2]]  is actually valid, but you wanted store value at given index , if i can reflect it to php you wanted [[1 => val, 2 => val],[1 => val, 2 => val]] this is invalid, you cant access property => val in javascript , array is  list of scalar value or list of object , if you want to given index attach value [[{ prop : val}]] , or  var arr = [[], [],] , and then arr[0].push(val) , you will end in [[val],[]] you cant do arr[0][0] = val

Comment: so teoreticall if you modify your code to  empty[counter1] = [], and then empty[counter1].push(data.fixtures[1]) you will end in empty[counter] = [value] , but you wanted access property [counter2++] of object empty[counter1] which was ofcourse undefined .

Comment: @JasonCust i am not saying its invalid, i am pointing that OP wanted to initialize 2D array as ovj = [[],[]] and he thinked that javascript will knows that it should be treated as 2D array, and any access to obj[n][o] is valid , but i wanted clarify , it is not valid in javascript world. And you cant access [o] index of [n] if it was not initialized, explicitly as you said in your answer.

Comment: @MilosMosovsky Got it. I didn't see that the OP was coming from a PHP perspective and that was his point of confusion. Yeah, initializing a 2D array in JS doesn't provide any magic for initializing further elements beyond the initial assignment.

Comment: I should have read your answer more carefully: The object literal notation `{}` is not the same as array notation `[]` (or `new Array()`). With `{}` you don't have the `length` property and you can not i-iterate over the array. So this part of your answer `[{},{},{}]` is not valid. As @JasonCust pointed out, OPs problem was that he just initialized first two indexes in the first dimension. You are coming to the same conclusion with `if(emtpy[counter1] === undefined)` BUT you have to initialize the array with `empty[counter1] = [];`